# Why is the following C code not returning 0 after the linked list is free'd from memory?

Tags: c, if-statement, pass-by-reference, free, pass-by-value

This function is supposed to delete linked list in C only if it is empty. The ll_length() function is confirmed working. If the linked list is successfully deleted, we are to return 0. If it is not deleted, return negative one. This program is returning -1. It enters the first if statement but not the second. What is wrong

```
ll_destroy(struct linked_list *ll)
{
  if (ll_length(ll) == 0){
    free(ll);
    if (ll == NULL){
      return 0; //remove 0 if removed   
     }
  }
  return -1; // if not deleted
}
```

Comment: `free` doesn't `NULL`ify the pointer it's freeing

Comment: What you are seeing is caused because `ll` is a pointer which is passed by value to the `free` function. So it does not get updated inside `free`.

Comment: It is not possible for `free()` to fail, so there is nothing to test for.  (Or rather, it can only fail if you've caused undefined behavior elsewhere in your program. e.g. by overrunning a buffer, in which case the behavior of `free()` is likewise undefined; it may crash or otherwise misbehave, but it has no nice way to signal such a condition.)

Answer (score 6):

After the call of `free`

```
free(ll);
```

the value of the pointer `ll` is not changed. The pointer was passed by value. That is the function `free` deals with a copy of the value of the passed pointer. So the substatement of the next if statement

```
if (ll == NULL){
```

will not get the control.

Just write

```
  if (ll_length(ll) == 0){
    free(ll);
    return 0; //return 0 if removed   
  }
  return -1; // if not deleted
```

if you want to change the passed pointer in the caller of the function then you need to pass it by reference. For example

```
int ll_destroy(struct linked_list **ll)
{
  if (ll_length(*ll) == 0){
    free( *ll);
    *ll = NULL;
    return 0;
  }
  return -1; // if not deleted
}
```

and in the caller you need to write

```
ll_destroy( &ll );
```